# Changes to React state within the Component(via mapDispatchToProps) gives error

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am following the Todo example of redux from here https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos

I have made some minor changes. I am accepting more fields in my todo. 
`{text, time, by}` and displaying these details in a table.

I want to order this table by time. I do *not* want to follow the redux pattern for this use case. Why you ask!

For something as simple as ordering I do not want to add this in the state. I want to maintain these functions within the `React state itself`. Since the VisibleTodoList is a smart component where its state has the todos I want to be able to reorder it the way I like to so.

My `VisibleTodoList.js`

```
const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
   case 'SHOW_ALL':
    return todos
   case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
    return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
   case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
    return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
   default:
    throw new Error('Unknown filter: ' + filter)
  }
 }

const orderTime = (todos) => {
 console.log('inside order time!'); //Displays this. comes inside here.
 return todos.filter(t => t.time > 20) //This gives me error!!
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter), // I do not want to add more things to the state. Want to keep it simple. 
})

const mapDispatchToProps =  ({
 onTodoClick: toggleTodo,
 onTimeClick: orderTime //My function defined above to returned filtered todos.
})

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)

export default VisibleTodoList
```

`TodoList.js` Looks like this

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, persons, onTodoClick, completed, onTimeClick}) => (
<div>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>Task Name</th>
    <th 
     onClick={() => onTimeClick(todos)}
     style={{
       textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
     }}>Time</th>
    <th>By person</th>
   </tr>
   {todos.map(todo =>
    <Todo
      key={todo.id}
      {...todo}
    />
  )}
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
)
```

My todo.js looks almost the same

```
const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text, time, by }) => (
  <tr key={text}>
   <td style={{
    textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>{text}</td>
    <td>{time}</td>
    <td>{by}</td>
  </tr>
)
```

I keep getting this error when I click on Time column
`Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

What am I doing wrong? 
Also what pattern should I be following to achieve this? Without deviating too much from the redux pattern. Will I have to use `setState`

To give more context I want to have a local UI state than having it in the redux store. Like explained here
[Should you ever use this.setState() when using redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711477/should-you-ever-use-this-setstate-when-using-redux)

**Update 1**: I do understand that because `orderTime` is not dispatching a object it is complaining. But my broader question if I had to do the achieve the same functionality. How would I have to do it? 
If I understand correctly I will have to use `setState` to do this.

Comment: The issue is that you're using `orderTime()` as an action-creator, but it's actually not. When you click the Time column, it dispatches whatever returns from `orderTime()`, which is not a plain object *but an array*.

Comment: Yes correct. I have edited my question to reflect the same.
I understand why I see the error. My question is how would I achieve something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I could come up with so far!

```
const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'WEIGHT_SORT':
      return _.sortBy(todos, [function(o) { return o.time; }]);
       default:
     throw new Error('Unknown filter: ' + filter)
   }
 }

class TodoList extends React.Component {

  state = { filter: 'SHOW_ALL' }

  handleShow = filter => {
    this.setState({ filter: 'WEIGHT_SORT' })
  }


render(){
  const filteredTodos = getVisibleTodos(todos, this.state.filter)
  return (
    <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <th>Task Name</th>
        <th 
         onClick={() => this.handleShow('SHOW_COMPLETED')}>Time</th>
        <th>By person</th>
       </tr>
       {filteredTodos.map(todo =>
        <Todo
          key={todo.id}
          {...todo}
          onClick={() => this.props.onTodoClick(todo.id)}
        />
       )}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  )
}
}
```

This being UI tweaks(ordering, sorting & other manipulations) we keep it in the React local state. This leads to cleaner code because our `redux state` is clean and does not store all of this information.

Open to suggestions/comments and a better answer!